# Editing Template Binding in control templates

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

I created a `ControlTemplate` like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="FieldTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
  <Border Background="LightGray" >
    <DockPanel >
      <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{TemplateBinding c1}" />
      <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{TemplateBinding c2}" />
      <TextBox />
    </DockPanel>
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

and now i want to be able to edit both textblocks, how do i do it?
I tried something like this and other variations but it didn't work:

```
<ContentControl c1="hello" c2="olleh" 
       Template="{StaticResource FieldTemplate}" x:Name="NameControl"/>
```

Comment: What is "c1"? Where did you define this property?

Comment: Nowhere, from your question I understand i needed to define it?.. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ContentControl` has no `c1` and `c2` properties. If you create a custom control and define these as dependency properties, it would work:

```
public class MyControl : ContentControl
{
    public string C1
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(C1Property); }
        set { SetValue(C1Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty C1Property = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(C1), typeof(string), typeof(MyControl));

    public string C2
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(C2Property); }
        set { SetValue(C2Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty C2Property = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(C2), typeof(string), typeof(MyControl));
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="FieldTemplate" TargetType="local:MyControl">
    <Border Background="LightGray" >
        <DockPanel >
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{TemplateBinding C1}" />
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{TemplateBinding C2}" />
            <TextBox />
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
...
<local:MyControl C1="hello" C2="olleh" Template="{StaticResource FieldTemplate}" x:Name="NameControl"/>
```